Why does this C program code produce the following results?
While studying about operators in language C, I wrote these codes:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 100, p = 50;
    
    if (m%=100 !=1 && m++ > 0) {
        printf("m=%d, p=%d\n", m, p);
    }
    else {
        printf("m=%d, p=%d\n", ++m, ++p);
    }

    return 0;
}


The result I expected was m=2, p=51, because the moment I came from the if block to the else block, I expected it to be m=1. However, the result I ran was always m=1, p=51. I tried to find out in my own way why this result came out, but my curiosity was not solved. Can you explain the solution process?

Does this answer your question? Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?

m % 100 is zero, and so is m++, so the if condition fails, so you enter the else block, so ++m was evaluated, as 1, and ++p as 51, so you printed m=1, p=51.

@Lundin Sometimes one wishes language implementations had an --how-are-you-actually-parsing-this?! flag. =)

When m has the value 100, I think there are three "reasonable" evaluations of the expression m%=100 !=1 && m++ > 0 :- (1) tmp = m + 1, m = tmp, m = m % 1 which sets m to 0 and follows the else branch, printing m=1, p=51; (2) tmp = m + 1, m = m % 1, m = tmp which sets m to 101 and follows the if branch, printing m=101, p=50; (3) m = m % 1, tmp = m + 1, m = tmp which sets m to 1 and follows the if branch, printing m=1, p=50. But as pointed out in @Lundin's answer, "anything can happen" due to UB.

This code is obfuscated. The operator precedence of m%=100 !=1 && m++ > 0 is:
Posfix ++ before > before != before && before %=.
At a glance we might be fooled to think that the sub-expression m%=100 !=1 is an operand of the &&. But the whole expression is to be parsed as:
m %= ( (100 !=1) && ( (m++) > 0) )

And here's a problematic bug. From Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators? we can learn that modifying a variable in an expression "unsequenced" in relation to a value computation or another modification of that same variable invokes undefined behavior and anything can happen.
Because while && has a sequence point and the left operand is guaranteed to be sequenced and evaluated before the right one, the m++ to the right is unsequenced in relation to the m %=. That's two unsequenced modifications of the same variable with no sequence point in between. So the code is really just a fancy way of writing something undefined like i = i++.
Since there is undefined behavior, anything can happen. Something happened, so there it is. One particular compiler apparently decided to evaluate the whole expression to zero, which is one possible outcome of "anything can happen". The program could as well crash.

The != operator has higher precedence than the %=, so the expression is evaluated as:
100 != 1, which is true (1), since 100 is not equal to 1.
m %= 1, which is equivalent to m = m % 1. Since m is initially 100, m % 1 is 0. So, m is updated to 0.
0 && m++ > 0: Here, the logical AND operator && is evaluated. Since the left operand 0 is false (0), the right operand m++ > 0 is not evaluated due to short-circuiting, and the entire expression evaluates to false (0).
